# Center a CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS code. I can't seem to get it centered. I've tried using display: inline-block and float: left. I've also tried using margins but it ends up messing up the dropdown box. I've tried editing everything but I can't get it right. I'm sorta new to this kinda thing. I would appreciate the help

```
body {
background-image:url('andromedagalaxy.jpg');
}
h1  {
text-align:center;
color: white;
}
p   {
text-align:center;
}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #0099CC; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block; text-align:center;
}
nav ul li {
float: left; 
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #000066;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%, #000066 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%, #000066 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%, #000066 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #000099; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #000066; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #000066;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000066;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #006699;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle from it? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zackattackk/eb2Zd/

Comment: Yes than my example of `nav { width:505px; margin: 0 auto}` will work

Comment: Check my answer is better to use `text-align`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It's centered now!

Comment: @user3244567 please if your question is solved now check the answer that helps you with the green check. :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help, just want to know why my answer was downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using this:

```
nav ul {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

To center that `ul` you can use `text-align` on the parent, try this:

```
nav {
  text-align:center;
}
```

You can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/eb2Zd/6/ to review the demo file.

Answer (score 0):

After providing us with a JsFiddle i have 2 examples for you.

**Example 1:** 
You should give your `nav` a `width` and `margin:0 auto`; Like in the example down here.

```
nav { width:505px; margin: 0 auto}
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/eb2Zd/7/)**

**Example 2:**

```
nav { text-align:center; }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/eb2Zd/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on the nav

```
nav {
 text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background-image:url('andromedagalaxy.jpg');
}
h1  {
text-align:center;
color: white;
}
p   {
text-align:center;
}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #0099CC; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-   serif;
text-align: center;
   }
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block; text-align:center;
}
 nav ul li {
float: left; 
 }
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #000066;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%;)
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000066 0%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #000099; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #000066; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #000066;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000066;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #006699;
        }
 nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
 }
 nav{
 text-align:center;
}
}




 http://jsfiddle.net/u8V9R/
```

Answer (score -1):

On the html, place inside a  which must be centered.
On the **CSS** file,  center by placing this

```
.center {position: relative; 
 margin-left:auto; 
 margin-right:auto; 
 text-align:center;
 }
```